# how to change the UISearchBar in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I am creating an application for iOS 7, where i need to add UISearchBar in my UITableView. Search functionality is working fine, my problem is i am trying to customize my search bar UI using below code to achieve my output as below screenshot:

[image]

**here is my code :**

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 29, 266, 27)];
searchBar.delegate = self;
searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-bar.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

NSDictionary *attributes =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
 [UIFont fontWithName:@"HPSimplifiedW01-Regular" size:14.0f], UITextAttributeFont,
 nil];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil]
 setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil]
 setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

for (UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews)
{
    for (UIView *secondLevelSubview in subView.subviews){
        if ([secondLevelSubview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            UITextField *searchBarTextField = (UITextField *)secondLevelSubview;
            searchBarTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
            //set font color here
            searchBarTextField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            searchBarTextField.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            if ([searchBarTextField respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedPlaceholder:)]) {
                UIColor *color = [UIColor whiteColor];
                searchBarTextField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Search" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color}];

                searchBarTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
                searchBarTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

                searchBarTextField.rightView = nil;
                searchBarTextField.leftView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
            }

            searchBarTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HPSimplifiedW04-LightItalic" size:15.0f];

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But currently using above code i am getting my output as below screenshot :

[image]

Can you please help me to achieve my output as first screen? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem in this case is, that most of the properties we would like to change are the view's layer properties, and not accessible by the appearance proxy. But there is a neat trick to change that:

We can wrap this attributes in category methods.

```
@interface UITextField (test)
- (void)setLayerCornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadiu;
- (void)setLayerBorderColor:(UIColor *)color;
- (void)setLayerBorderWidth:(CGFloat)width;
@end

@implementation UITextField (test)

- (void)setLayerCornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
}

-(void)setLayerBorderColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    self.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor;
}

-(void)setLayerBorderWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    self.layer.borderWidth = width;
}
@end
```

With

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundColor:self.searchBar.barTintColor];
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setLayerCornerRadius:15];
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setLayerBorderColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setLayerBorderWidth:1];
```

we achieve

[image: screen]

`barTintColor` is set in the storyboard

to get rid of the magnifier glass icon, we can do this

```
[self.searchBar setImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image: screen 2]

Now the hardest part was to get the placeholder text left aligned.

Therefor I subclassed UISearchBar like

```
@interface MySearchBar : UISearchBar

@end

@implementation MySearchBar

-(void)setAlternatePropmtLabel:(UILabel *)alternatePropmtLabel
{
    UILabel *l = (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:1991];
    l = alternatePropmtLabel;
    [self addSubview:l];
    l.tag = 1991;
}

-(UILabel *)alternatePropmtLabel
{
    return (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:1991];
}


@end
```

add added

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[[self superview] viewWithTag:1991] setHidden:YES];
}
```

to the textfield category. (You should replace `1991` with some nice identifier)
In the storyboard I set `MySearchBar` as a custom class for the search bar.

Now by using

```
UILabel *promtLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 100, 44)];
promtLabel.text = @"prompt";
[(MySearchBar *)self.searchBar setAlternatePropmtLabel:promtLabel];
```

I get

[image]

with "prompt" disappearing on the first touch.

---

The complete code, tweaked a bit:

[image]

```
#import "ViewController.h"

static NSUInteger kAlternatePlaceHolderTag = 1991;

@interface MySearchBar : UISearchBar

@end

@implementation MySearchBar

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
}


-(void)setAlternatePlaceholderLabel:(UILabel *)alternatePlaceholderLabel
{
    UILabel *l = (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:kAlternatePlaceHolderTag];
    l = alternatePlaceholderLabel;
    [self addSubview:l];
    l.tag = kAlternatePlaceHolderTag;
}

-(UILabel *)alternatePlaceholderLabel
{
    return (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:kAlternatePlaceHolderTag];
}


@end



@interface UITextField (test)
- (void)setLayerCornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius;
- (void)setLayerBorderColor:(UIColor *)color;
- (void)setLayerBorderWidth:(CGFloat)width;
@end

@implementation UITextField (test)

- (void)setLayerCornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
}

-(void)setLayerBorderColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    self.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor;
}

-(void)setLayerBorderWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    self.layer.borderWidth = width;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[[self superview] viewWithTag:kAlternatePlaceHolderTag] setHidden:YES];
}


@end



@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.searchBar setImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];

    UILabel *promtLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(22, 0, 100, 44)];
    promtLabel.text = @"prompt";
    promtLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Italic" size:12];
    promtLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [(MySearchBar *)self.searchBar setAlternatePlaceholderLabel:promtLabel];

    [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundColor:self.searchBar.barTintColor];
    [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
    [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setLayerCornerRadius:15];
    [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setLayerBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setLayerBorderWidth:1];


}


@end
```

Comment: @vikingosegundaThanks for your reply, here you have created custom UISearchBar class, is it possible to change placeholder alignment as left corner using default UISearchBar?

Comment: Well, yes, via a category and associated objects. But why can't u subclass?

Comment: Can you help me for the same, i have updated my question. Your answer is totally correct but i want to know my mistake in my code for placeholder position, rest is working fine. Thanks

Comment: Well, it is 3:30 in the morning here. Reading other people's code is hard at that time.

Comment: I don't see any code to reposition the placeholder. and there is no open api to do so.

Comment: You try to position by using text alignment. but if you have a close look at the placeholder text animation once you clicked the bar, you will see that it must be a view that is animated by position. the alignment is unusable here. You should be aware, that the view hierarchy of UISearchBar could change without notice, therefor your nested for-loop could break. That said I have to confess that also my overwriting go touchBegan: in a category is dangerous. a gesture recognizer could be healthier.